How to instruct nmake where to find targets and put output across different directories?
I am trying to compile a c program but am having difficulty getting nmake to place object files where I want them.
My directory structure is as follows:
C:.
├───src
│   └───obj
├───library
└───librarysrc

The contents of my makefile, which is in src, is as follows:
# Define directories
SRC_DIR = .
LIBSRC_DIR = ..\librarysrc
OBJ_DIR = .\obj
LIB_DIR = ..\library

# Define variables
CC = cl
CFLAGS = /MT /I $(LIBSRC_DIR) /I $(SRC_DIR) /nologo /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /W4 /Od /DDEBUG
LIBB = lib
LIBFLAGS = /OUT:$(LIB_DIR)\integrate.lib /nologo

# Define target names
LIB_OBJ = $(LIBSRC_DIR)\*.obj
SRC_OBJ = $(OBJ_DIR)\*.obj
LIBRARY = $(LIB_DIR)\integrate.lib
TARGET = $(SRC_DIR)\my_program.exe

# Default target
all: $(TARGET)

# Pattern rule to compile all .c files in libsrc to .obj files in obj
{$(LIBSRC_DIR)}.c{$(LIBSRC_DIR)}.obj::
    @echo Compiling $<
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) /c $< 

# Rule to create the static library
$(LIBRARY): $(LIB_OBJ)
    @echo Creating library $(LIBRARY)
    $(LIBB) $(LIBFLAGS) $(LIB_OBJ)


# Pattern rule to compile all .c files in src to .obj files in obj
{$(SRC_DIR)}.c{$(OBJ_DIR)}.obj::
    @echo Compiling $<
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) /c $< 

# Rule to compile the main program
$(TARGET): $(SRC_OBJ) $(LIBRARY)
    @echo Compiling and linking to create $(TARGET)
    $(CC) /nologo /Fe$(TARGET) $(SRC_OBJ) $(LIBRARY)


# Clean up intermediate files
clean:
    @echo Cleaning up...
    del $(OBJ_DIR)\*.obj $(LIBSRC_DIR)\*.obj $(LIBRARY) $(TARGET)


On running nmake, I was expecting the .obj files associated with the library to end up in ..\librarysrc\ and those for the files in src to end up in src\obj
In fact they all end up in src and the following commands then fail as they can't find the required object files.
Any suggestions on how to fix this would be very much appreciated!

You need to use the/Fo option on your compile statements to tell the compiler where to store the object files.
